# Larmor equation and decelerated particles

Tags: particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation

From the Larmor equation: $P=\frac{q^2a^2}{6\pi\epsilon_0c^3}$ so an accelerated particle radiate. Is this true also for a decelerated particle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In physics, we use the term "acceleration" to refer to more than just an increase in speed. The word "acceleration" refers to all situations where the *velocity vector* changes. This could mean that the speed increases, or the speed decreases, or it could mean that the speed stays the same and the direction of motion changes.

So, when we say "an accelerating particle radiates", this includes deceleration, by definition. It also, importantly, includes moving in a circle at a constant speed (which is one of the most relevant applications of the Larmor formula in, for example, accelerator physics).